# dictionary binding MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Code in my view is as follows:

```
@model Dictionary<Project, List<ProjectActualCapacity>>

var model2 = Model.ToList();

@for (int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(r => model2[i].Key.Name)
            </td>
            @for (int j = 0; j < model2[i].Value.Count(); j++)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(r => model2[i].Value[j].Hours, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(r => model2[i].Value[j].ID)
                </td>
            }

            @Html.HiddenFor(r => model2[i].Key.ID)
        </tr>
    }
```

Why isnt the controller binding the model on POST request?

```
public ActionResult ProjectActualCapacityIndex(IDictionary<Project, List<ProjectActualCapacity>> model2)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you're not providing enough information for the Model Binder to do it's work.

What you should do is create the appropriate DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplates for each of your types and then use `@Html.DisplayFor(...)` and `@Html.EditorFor(...)` relatively.

The view you posted would then become:

```
@model Dictionary<Project, List<ProjectActualCapacity>>

@for (int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(r => Model[i].Key)
        </td>
        @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Value.Count(); j++)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => Model[i].Value[j])
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Model Binding is a bit of a brain frazzler. Basically every element of a type has to be in the body and named in a certain way for the framework to go "ah-ha, you mean _this_ type" and populate it correctly. Using Display and EditorTemplates makes life much easier in terms of naming the elements correctly. Look at the names in the HTML produced by the View now and hopefully it will be clearer what it does.

Comment: It is weird because the only difference is the class of the input element. Editor for creates an input with class="text-box single-line"